# Monitor downloaded bytes when streaming via AvPlayerItem and AvPlayer - iOS

Tags: ios, mp3, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I want to monitor downloaded bytes when streaming mp3 from an URL and print it out to an IULabel. I can't find any easy method to do that.

What about "AVPlayerItemAccessLog", does it have the information? I can't figure out how to use that? Does anybody know how to get such information?

Below is my code for play the stream:

```
-(void)play
{
    /*Allow radio to run in background*/
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil]; 

    /*Gets the url fra sender*/
    NSString *urlString=  self.radioStation.url;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    /*Stop the radio if its play or have info*/
    if(self.avPlayerItem)
    {
        [self stop];

    }


    /*Sets the Avplayeritem*/
    self.avPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    /*Listen for changes in the avPlayerItem*/    
    [self.avPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];   

    /*Sets the avplayer with avplayeritem*/
    self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.avPlayerItem];

    /*Sends loading info to the nortification*/
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Loading" object:self];

    /*Plays the radio*/
    [self.avPlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use KVO on the AVPlayerItem to get this information. Something like this:

```
[self.player.currentItem addObserver:self
                          forKeyPath:@"loadedTimeRanges"
                             options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                             context:NULL];
```

And then the standard observer method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    // Get the player item's loadedTimeRanges value here.
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observers before releasing the player item.